# aspboilerplate stored procedure not working with distinct database tenants

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, abp

Currently i am developing a multi tenant application using aspboilerplate framework. I need to execute storedprocedures. I have followed the way mentioned in this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1199648/Using-Stored-Procedure-User-Defined-Function-and-V) . I have created a distinct tenant with separate database and try to execute the stored procedure against that db. But it always executing in the default tenant database. When i check the active transaction connection string that also returning default database connection. Please help. Other methods without sp working fine with distinct tenants.

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve by myself. There is a task i forgot to await. Also i need to set the tenant id in the unit of work manager since i am running a background job.